# What will happen if one of the four elements disappears?

Tags: natural-resources, classical-elements

Suppose that one of the 4 elements (earth, water, fire, air) will cease to exist in 20 years.

What will happen to the world? And what will happen to humankind?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Unfortunately, "open-ended, hypothetical questions" don't work well in our format (see more here: http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask and here: http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Can you narrow this down to something we can answer more concretely?

Comment: Currently your question is too broad. Is there an aspect of societey that you are especially interested in? That would help to narrow it down. Otherwise your question might be put on hold for some time. This is a standard procedure around here to make sure questions fit the guidelines and that edits to a question don't invalidate existing answers (we are a little different from other SEs). After some edits your question can be reopened. If you have any questions don't hesitate to @Username us to ask, or go to Meta or (with 20 reputation) to the chat to ask for help. Have fun!

Comment: This might be more answerable if you narrowed it down to one element, and specified what you mean by that element 'ending'. Does it just mean that all manifestations of that element disappear? Because I'd think if earth disappeared, there would be no world or humankind left.

Comment: Fire is more of a process than something you can just take away. Also, can you just ignite things back? Easiest with Earth. Everybody dies, no one left to care ;)

Comment: The question assumes that there *are* 4 elements. But this was found to be wrong quite a long time ago, as @Necessity says there are 115. It's like asking "What if the density of the Ether was reduced?" when we know the Ether doesn't exist. You must first build a world, including the physical laws, where there are 4 elements and go from there. e.g. "Wood burns so wood contains fire". What happens to wood if all the fire disappears. Does it just refuse to burn or does it look completely different? Does it lose its heat and become icy to touch? It's up to you.

Answer (score 11):

Earth disapears; The earth earth beneath us will literally disapear and we die.

Water disappears; Humans are about 70% water, so we die. Even excluding that, we don't drink for 3 days, we die.

Fire disappears; it would take a max of 18 minutes(probably) to freeze to death.

Air disappears; We suffocate and die.

We would die any which way.

Comment: I was going to answer but you pretty much sum everything up.

Comment: Does the sun count as fire? It's more of a thermo-nuclear reaction...

Comment: @colmde Scientically, fire is the reaction of fuel, oxygen and heat. So the sun is not a fire. However if you look at it from The Elements, the sun is a Yang Fire. So... (shrug).

Comment: Actually, that wouldn't be right by the greek version of the elements(the four elements), it would be aristotle's fifth aether. However I never did like that version, so I am a bit bias.

Comment: @Necessity Science has nothing to do with the four elements

Comment: @Mołot Agreed, Science has 115 Known elements :)